# Will growing more trees in random forests increase the variance compared to growing fewer trees?

Tags: machine-learning, trees, decision-trees

Elements of mathematical learning says that less tress are not required to obtain a good predictive performance but does that mean growing more trees in random forests will increase the variance compared to growing fewer trees?

[image]

Comment: Your trees are in a jungle with a very foggy atmosphere... The variance of which random variable ? Which trees are you speaking about (binary, weighted...) ? Prediction of which performance ? etc. **Give precisions, please.**

Comment: @JeanMarie The variance in the Bias-Variance Tradeoff. I have posted the tree definition above (I guess decision trees).

Comment: Thanks. It's better like this...